# Why is Postfix using a lookup table?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, smtp, postfix

I am trying to send mail locally using Postfix. What I can't understand, is why a lookup table is being used.

I am attempting a minimal Postfix build from source, so have omitted berkley DB support. As such, I am not expecting postfix to know how to read a Berkley DB formatted file. My question is, why is postfix trying to ? Is there no way to avoid a table lookup, even for minimal postfix installations ?

### The steps I have taken

First, I run: `./sendmail -t root@localhost`
And enter a message:

```
Hi there,
bye.
.
```

All seems well.
I then check my Postfix log, which states:

```sh
Mar 17 18:02:22 USERNAME postfix/qmgr[117616]: ID: from=<root@USERNAME.localdomain>, size=317, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 18:02:22 USERNAME postfix/qmgr[117616]: ID: from=<root@USERNAME.localdomain>, size=323, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 18:02:22 USERNAME postfix/local[118209]: error: unsupported dictionary type: hash
Mar 17 18:02:22 USERNAME postfix/local[118209]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Mar 17 18:02:22 USERNAME postfix/local[118209]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: hash
Mar 17 18:02:22 USERNAME postfix/local[118209]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases: lookup of 'root' failed
Mar 17 18:02:22 USERNAME postfix/local[118210]: error: unsupported dictionary type: hash
Mar 17 18:02:22 USERNAME postfix/local[118210]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Mar 17 18:02:22 USERNAME postfix/local[118210]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: hash
Mar 17 18:02:22 USERNAME postfix/local[118210]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases: lookup of 'root' failed
Mar 17 18:02:22 USERNAME postfix/local[118209]: ID: to=<root@localhost>, relay=local, delay=1148, delays=1148/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (alias database unavailable)
Mar 17 18:02:22 USERNAME postfix/local[118210]: ID: to=<root@localhost>, relay=local, delay=1115, delays=1115/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (alias database unavailable)
```

Based on this log, I infer that the mail successfully passes the postfix/qmgr process, and encounters issues during the postfix/local process.

My `main.cf` file is:

```sh
compatibility_level = 3.9
queue_directory = /srv/mail/postfix/queue
command_directory = /srv/mail/postfix/sbin
daemon_directory = /srv/mail/postfix/daemon
data_directory = /srv/mail/postfix/data
mail_owner = postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /srv/mail/postfix/sendmail
newaliases_path = /srv/mail/postfix/newaliases
mailq_path = /srv/mail/postfix/mailq
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = /srv/mail/postfix/html
manpage_directory = /srv/mail/postfix/man
sample_directory = /srv/mail/postfix/conf
readme_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
shlib_directory = no
meta_directory = /srv/mail/postfix/meta
mailbox_command=
maillog_file_prefixes=/srv/mail/postfix
maillog_file=/srv/mail/postfix/logs/mail.log
```

There is no mention of the `hash` table format here. I do notice that the `hash` format is mentioned in the default settings. Running `./postconf -d | grep hash` returns:

```sh
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases
default_database_type = hash
hash_queue_depth = 1
hash_queue_names = deferred, defer
```

Can anyone experienced fill me on whether Postfix has a built in need to use a database of some sort ? Where does this occur ?

My next plan is to build postfix with MySQL support and use the `mysql:name` format - I would prefer to go without any database as I am attempting a minimal build.

Answer (score 0):

> is why a lookup table is being used.

To implement its "alias" functionality.

Disabling BDB is not the same as disabling all functionality that relies on lookup tables. All that you've disabled is one of 20+ different *backends* for lookup tables, but you haven't disabled the overall concept of lookup tables – or mailbox aliases for that matter.

> Can anyone experienced fill me on whether Postfix has a built in need to use a database of some sort ? Where does this occur ?

It occurs in the default settings, which you've just found in the previous paragraph.

The default settings are not an all-or-nothing – they are applied individually to each parameter that you don't explicitly specify. So if you haven't set `alias_maps` to something custom, then Postfix will use `hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases` as the default value.

To avoid this, set `alias_maps` to something custom.

See the [DATABASE_README](https://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html) for alternatives if you don't want BDB. The "texthash:" type would be the closest equivalent for small maps, relying on an in-memory hashtable. Very small maps can be specified inline using "inline:" (for multiple entries) or "static:" (catch-all).

Answer (score 0):

Postfix uses hash-tables to organize much of its data.

The Postfix documentation describes it in the article
[The Postfix lookup table model](https://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html):

> Postfix uses lookup tables to store and look up information for access
> control, address rewriting and even for content filtering. All Postfix
> lookup tables are specified as "type:table", where "type" is one of
> the database types described under "Postfix lookup table types" at the
> end of this document, and where "table" is the lookup table name. The
> Postfix documentation uses the terms "database" and "lookup table" for
> the same thing.
>
> Examples of lookup tables that appear often in the Postfix
> documentation:
>
> ```
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>     alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases            (local aliasing)
>     header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks (content filtering)
>     transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport      (routing table)
>     virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual    (virtual aliasing)
> ```
>
> All Postfix lookup tables store information as (key, value) pairs.
> This interface may seem simplistic at first, but it turns out to be
> very powerful. The (key, value) query interface completely hides the
> complexities of LDAP or SQL from Postfix. This is a good example of
> connecting complex systems with simple interfaces.

Hash tables are a pretty efficient way of organizing key-value pairs,
where the hash is done on the key as a means of finding the value,
even if it's empty (as described in the documentation).

You may read about Hash tables in
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).